# Ansible SSH error: Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host 10.10.201.1 port 22: Connection refused

Tags: ssh, ansible, sshpass

I have an Ansible server that I use to deploy a virtual machine on my VMware datacenter.
Once the VM deployed, Ansible has to connect to VM for adding the sources list and install applications.

However, 9 times out of 10 ansible does not connect to VM:

```
[2019/10/07 07:04:30][INFO] ansible-playbook /etc/ansible/jobs/deploy_application.yml -e "{'vm_name': '_TEST01', 'datacenter': 'Demo-Center'}" --tags "apt_sources" -vvv
[2019/10/07 07:04:32][INFO] ansible-playbook 2.8.3
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/home/imperium/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 2.7.15+ (default, Jul  9 2019, 16:51:35) [GCC 7.4.0]
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
host_list declined parsing /etc/ansible/hosts as it did not pass it's verify_file() method
script declined parsing /etc/ansible/hosts as it did not pass it's verify_file() method
auto declined parsing /etc/ansible/hosts as it did not pass it's verify_file() method
Parsed /etc/ansible/hosts inventory source with ini plugin

PLAYBOOK: deploy_application.yml *************************************************************************************************
4 plays in /etc/ansible/jobs/deploy_application.yml

PLAY [Création de la VM depuis un template] **************************************************************************************
META: ran handlers
META: ran handlers
META: ran handlers

PLAY [Démarrage de la VM] ********************************************************************************************************
META: ran handlers
META: ran handlers
META: ran handlers

PLAY [Inventaire dynamique de la VM] *********************************************************************************************
META: ran handlers

TASK [include_vars] **************************************************************************************************************
task path: /etc/ansible/jobs/deploy_application.yml:51
ok: [10.10.200.100] => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "vsphere_host": "10.10.200.100",
        "vsphere_pass": "Demo-NX01",
        "vsphere_user": "administrator@demo-nxo.local"
    },
    "ansible_included_var_files": [
        "/etc/ansible/group_vars/vsphere_credentials.yml"
    ],
    "changed": false
}

TASK [Récupération de l'adresse IP de la VM] *************************************************************************************
task path: /etc/ansible/jobs/deploy_application.yml:52
<localhost> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: imperium
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'echo ~imperium && sleep 0'
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /home/imperium/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1570431871.22-272720170721626 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1570431871.22-272720170721626="` echo /home/imperium/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1570431871.22-272720170721626 `" ) && sleep 0'
Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/modules/cloud/vmware/vmware_guest_facts.py
<localhost> PUT /home/imperium/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-28654XuKRxH/tmpuNQmT5 TO /home/imperium/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1570431871.22-272720170721626/AnsiballZ_vmware_guest_facts.py
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /home/imperium/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1570431871.22-272720170721626/ /home/imperium/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1570431871.22-272720170721626/AnsiballZ_vmware_guest_facts.py && sleep 0'
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/python2 /home/imperium/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1570431871.22-272720170721626/AnsiballZ_vmware_guest_facts.py && sleep 0'
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'rm -f -r /home/imperium/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1570431871.22-272720170721626/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
ok: [10.10.200.100 -> localhost] => {
    "changed": false,
    "instance": {
        "annotation": "2019/10/07 07:03",
        "current_snapshot": null,
        "customvalues": {},
        "guest_consolidation_needed": false,
        "guest_question": null,
        "guest_tools_status": "guestToolsRunning",
        "guest_tools_version": "10346",
        "hw_cluster": "Cluster A",
        "hw_cores_per_socket": 1,
        "hw_datastores": [
            "datastore 1"
        ],
        "hw_esxi_host": "dc-lab-esxi01.datacenter-nxo.local",
        "hw_eth0": {
            "addresstype": "manual",
            "ipaddresses": [
                "10.10.201.1",
                "fe80::250:56ff:fe91:4f39"
            ],
            "label": "Network adapter 1",
            "macaddress": "00:50:56:91:4f:39",
            "macaddress_dash": "00-50-56-91-4f-39",
            "portgroup_key": null,
            "portgroup_portkey": null,
            "summary": "App_Repo_Network"
        },
        "hw_eth1": {
            "addresstype": "manual",
            "ipaddresses": [
                "10.10.200.200",
                "fe80::250:56ff:fe91:a20c"
            ],
            "label": "Network adapter 2",
            "macaddress": "00:50:56:91:a2:0c",
            "macaddress_dash": "00-50-56-91-a2-0c",
            "portgroup_key": "dvportgroup-66",
            "portgroup_portkey": "33",
            "summary": "DVSwitch: 50 11 7a 5c cc a2 c6 a7-1b 91 16 ac e1 16 66 e9"
        },
        "hw_files": [
            "[datastore 1] _TEST01/_TEST01.vmx",
            "[datastore 1] _TEST01/_TEST01.nvram",
            "[datastore 1] _TEST01/_TEST01.vmsd",
            "[datastore 1] _TEST01/_TEST01.vmdk"
        ],
        "hw_folder": "/Demo-Center/vm/Ansible",
        "hw_guest_full_name": "Ubuntu Linux (64-bit)",
        "hw_guest_ha_state": true,
        "hw_guest_id": "ubuntu64Guest",
        "hw_interfaces": [
            "eth0",
            "eth1"
        ],
        "hw_is_template": false,
        "hw_memtotal_mb": 4096,
        "hw_name": "_TEST01",
        "hw_power_status": "poweredOn",
        "hw_processor_count": 2,
        "hw_product_uuid": "42113a25-217d-29dc-57a8-564c66b40239",
        "hw_version": "vmx-13",
        "instance_uuid": "50110317-76f7-dd1b-1cd1-e1e7c7ecf6f9",
        "ipv4": "10.10.201.1",
        "ipv6": null,
        "module_hw": true,
        "snapshots": [],
        "vnc": {}
    },
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "datacenter": "Demo-Center",
            "folder": "Ansible",
            "hostname": "10.10.200.100",
            "name": "_TEST01",
            "name_match": "first",
            "password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
            "port": 443,
            "properties": null,
            "schema": "summary",
            "tags": false,
            "use_instance_uuid": false,
            "username": "administrator@demo-nxo.local",
            "uuid": null,
            "validate_certs": false
        }
    }
}

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************************************************
task path: /etc/ansible/jobs/deploy_application.yml:64
ok: [10.10.200.100] => {
    "msg": "10.10.201.1"
}

TASK [Création d'un hôte temporaire dans l'inventaire] ***************************************************************************
task path: /etc/ansible/jobs/deploy_application.yml:65
creating host via 'add_host': hostname=10.10.201.1
changed: [10.10.200.100] => {
    "add_host": {
        "groups": [
            "vm"
        ],
        "host_name": "10.10.201.1",
        "host_vars": {}
    },
    "changed": true
}
META: ran handlers
META: ran handlers

PLAY [Mise à jour des adresses des dépôts] ***************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***********************************************************************************************************
task path: /etc/ansible/jobs/deploy_application.yml:73
<10.10.201.1> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: ansible
<10.10.201.1> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d11 ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'User="ansible"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/imperium/.ansible/cp/3c7b71383c 10.10.201.1 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~ansible && sleep 0'"'"''
<10.10.201.1> (255, '', 'ssh: connect to host 10.10.201.1 port 22: Connection refused\r\n')
fatal: [10.10.201.1]: UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host 10.10.201.1 port 22: Connection refused",
    "unreachable": true
}

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************************************
10.10.200.100              : ok=4    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
10.10.201.1                : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

On the VM side, the below message is reported:

```
Connection closed by authenticating user ansible 10.10.201.1 port 53098 [preauth]
```

The command run by Ansible:

```
sshpass -d11 ssh -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'User="ansible"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/imperium/.ansible/cp/3c7b71383c 10.10.201.1 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~ansible && sleep 0'"'"''
```

Without "sshpass -d11" the command working.

With the parameter "-d11", I have the below error:

```
root@IMPERIUM:~# sshpass -d11 ssh -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'User="ansible"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/imperium/.ansible/cp/3c7b71383c 10.10.201.1 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~ansible && sleep 0'"'"''
Permission denied, please try again.
```

Can you help me?

Comment: "Connection closed by authenticating user ansible..." Where exactly is this error message appearing? Can you tell what process is producing it?

Comment: Hello, this error appears (/var/log/auth.log) when I manually run the sshpass command used by Ansible. I create the VM from a template.